# In PowerShell, how do you set-content to a new child directory?

Tags: powershell

I have this to make file in current directory:

```
% { (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadData($_) | Set-Content -Path $_ -Encoding Byte };
```

...and I was trying some like:

```
% { (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadData($_) | Set-Content -Path ..\qq\$_ -Encoding Byte };
```

So... it doesn't work for some reason!
I know something was missing, but totally forgot how to do it D;

[EDIT]
I can do instead `Set-Content` something like `New-Item` and resolve the "path" problem but it doesnt accept `-Encoding Byte` and the final files will be broke.

Comment: Maybe you could provide the actual error. Does the relative path "..\qq" actually exist? What if you give it an absolute path instead? set a variable for it - `$outpath = c:\temp\qq`. Then call it `set-content -path "$outpath\$_"`

Comment: Is the error happening when you start the script directly in the directory without Visual Studio or PowerShell ISE?

Comment: It's a "parent -> child" path problem...

[This docs says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/managing-current-location?view=powershell-7) "In the some1\some2 folder, a period (.) represents some1\some2 and double periods (..) represent some1"

Direct in powershell console or any saved script, this might work right?

My current path is "inside some2", and was trying save the "set-content encoded bytes" in a child folder (with name "qq" who already exists) from a "parent of actual path".

Comment: In fact I can change to one more simpler way moving the target folder inside current path, and it's only save with ".\qq\" but doesnt work too. '-'     So.... I think the problem is `Set-Content` makes a new file using the final part of "path" as "file name", and I dunno how to handle this. I can only think to solve this with after save the files from `Set-Content` move to the right place with `Move-Item` but it's annoying all times do this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the MSDN [docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-5.1):

```
Set-Content -Path .\DateTime.txt -Value (Get-Date)
```

Below example downloads a 1MB big test file and stores the content to a temporary file:

```
$tempFile = New-TemporaryFile
Set-Content -Value (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadData("http://ovh.net/files/1Mb.dat") -Path $tempFile -Encoding Byte
Get-Content $tempFile
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: When pipe the contents **or not like the way you said** is the same path problem when I'm trying the change target folder... So.. See my two new coments right there, it's more richer in details. >< And thx for helping!